# Deleting an EKEvent from device's calendar using its identifier

Tags: ios6, ekevent, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I am creating EKEvent, saving it and saving its identifier as well. I wanna access this identifier and delete the specific Event. I am able to retrieve the proper Identifier from database. However, the Event isn't getting deleted from my Device's calendar.
My code to delete the event :
`NSError* err;

```
    EKEvent *myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:homeobj.eventDB];

    myEvent = [homeobj.eventDB eventWithIdentifier:[dbObj selectEventIdentifier:mypass]];

    [homeobj.eventDB removeEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deleting use this code

```
-(void)removeMeWithIndex:(int)index
{
    EKEvent* eventToRemove = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:[arrayofEventId objectAtIndex:index]];

    if (eventToRemove != nil) {
        NSError* error = nil;
        [eventStore removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
    }
}

-(IBAction)remove
{
  [self removeMeWithIndex:0];
}
```

I have updated my code to check if id exists or not as

```
-(void)removeMeWithIndex:(int)index
{
    NSLog(@"id is %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id"]);
    EKEvent* eventToRemove = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id"]];

    if (eventToRemove != nil) {
        NSError* error = nil;
        [eventStore removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
    }
}
```

output after deletion is ...

2013-06-26 18:51:43.999 CARL[674:907] id is 7AFE7AC2-111A-446F-86E6-8D69AD38F1AF:CA946E83-BE08-44AB-8834-06E1E4BFF7E8

your id is something like this ?

After creation of event check in calendar app in device.

[image]

After deleting event completion screenshot is :--

[image]

Here you can get [sample project.](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/3pZuhIk/0/blob?download)

Comment: I am storing my Event Identifier in Database, and accessing it from another Viewcontroller to delete it. How do i proceed then ??

Comment: now what can I do for you? you have output working perfectly.Even if setting id to user defaults while saving events and relaunching app then delete it.

Comment: Do i need to delete that id compulsorily from my database ? I am not getting link wat difference will it make by removing it from Database..!

Comment: If event is deleted then id from database must be deleted by you.

Comment: Thanks man...It helped me..I just had to delete the identifier from my  database n it worked..!